# How do I check if all numbers if a Columns are identical in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Below is my code 

Sub DeleteUneccessarySerial()
Dim rng As Range
Dim myNum As Long
myNum = 1
Set rng = Range("F:F")
Columns("A:I").Sort key1:=Range("I:I"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
Range("$A1:I200").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="Checked"
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, myNum) = rng.Count Then MsgBox ("All the same!")

Range("A:B,F:F,G:H").Delete
End Sub
```

What I would like to happen is to stop running the Macro if any number other that *1* exists in **Column `F`**. If all numbers are "**1**" in **Column `F`** than continue running the code.

I figure the problem is the last bit of code below 
"`If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, myNum) = rng.Count Then MsgBox ("All the same!")`"

Comment: `If  application.Min(rng) = mynum and application.max(rng) = mynum then`

Comment: @ScottCraner `Application.Max` is a latebound call to `WorksheetFunction.Max`, so it is slower, and doesn't have intellisense, and has different error handling. Also, a call to `Max` *and* `Min`, was 33% slower than a single call to `CountIf`, in my testing on 1048576 cells, because I assume the range only needs to be scanned once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure your `If` block to determine the program flow, and use `Exit Sub` to exit the procedure, as per this code:

```
Sub DeleteUneccessarySerial()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim myNum As Long
    myNum = 1
    Set rng = Range("F:F")
    Columns("A:I").Sort key1:=Range("I:I"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    Range("$A1:I200").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="Checked"
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, myNum) = rng.Count Then
        MsgBox ("All the same!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Range("A:B,F:F,G:H").Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Unless the OP has the whole column of 1048576 cells in column F filled it will never equal rng.count.  Probably want to do `WorksheetFunction.Count(rng)` instead.